# MigraDoc - Find out if a column has any cells

Tags: c#, migradoc

I have a piece of logic I need to complete, but have not yet come up with a decent answer.

I have a MigraDoc table and I want to get the ID of the next column that has not yet had any cells added to any rows:

```
        int nextEmptyColumnId = 0;

        for (int col = 0; col < inSectionTable.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            if (!"Are there any cells in table.Columns[col]")
            {
                nextEmptyColumnId = col;
                break;
            }
        }
```

As you may guess I am struggling to find what to put in the bit:

**"Are there any cells in table.Columns[col]"**

Comment: What is the type of `table.Columns[col]` ?

Comment: It is a MigraDoc table Column object

Answer (score 0):

I have (effectively) managed it with the following:

```
        for (int col = 0; col < inSectionTable.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            if (inSectionTable.Rows.Count <= numHeaderRows)
            {
                nextEmptyColumnId = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                nextEmptyColumnId = inSectionTable.Rows[numHeaderRows].Cells.Count;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Any better suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Your code locates the first column in the last row that does not have data yet. In the question you write "the next column that has not yet had any cells added to any rows". Which result do you expect if the first data row is full, but the second row has empty cells?

Comment: In my specific example I am populating a table very specifically column at a time... Unusual I know but it is the requirement given the datasets I am provided with and the specific order of the final table I need to present.